# Looping through ranges by columns in different worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have got a macro that needs to loop according to the number of columns that exist in the Worksheet "NSA" (not counting the dates), as in the image below:

[image]

Looping through the columns, the macro needs to fill the corresponding range in the worksheet "SA" with a random number, one column at a time.

I want to fill one column of "SA" for each time the loop occurs in "NSA", as to keep different numbers in B:B and C:C.

Thus, in the first time the code runs, I would like to insert data only in column B and, in the second time, fill only the column C.

That's where my code fails. It always fills both columns B and C in the worksheet "SA" at the same time, each time it runs. This is what I get (for a random value):
[image]

How could I change the loop so the columns in "SA" change only one at a time, according to the loop in "NSA"?

Thanks for the help.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Dessaz2()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

Dim wsNSA As Worksheet
Set wsNSA = wb1.Worksheets("NSA")

Dim wsSA As Worksheet
Set wsSA = wb1.Worksheets("SA")

Dim col1 As Range
Dim col2 As Range

LR = wsNSA.Cells(3, 1).End(xlDown).Row
LC = wsNSA.Cells(3, 1).End(xlToRight).Column


For Each col1 In wsNSA.Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(LR, LC)).Columns
wsNSA.Activate


wsSA.Activate

x = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 100)
wsSA.Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(LR, LC)) = x

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill col1.column each time :

```
Sub Dessaz2()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

Dim wsNSA As Worksheet
Set wsNSA = wb1.Worksheets("NSA")

Dim wsSA As Worksheet
Set wsSA = wb1.Worksheets("SA")

Dim col1 As Range
Dim col2 As Range

LR = wsNSA.Cells(3, 1).End(xlDown).Row
LC = wsNSA.Cells(3, 1).End(xlToRight).Column


For Each col1 In wsNSA.Range(wsNSA.Cells(3, 2), wsNSA.Cells(LR, LC)).Columns
wsNSA.Activate


wsSA.Activate

x = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 100)
wsSA.Range(wsSA.Cells(3, col1.Column), wsSA.Cells(LR, col1.Column)) = x

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Main()
    Dim rng as Range, cl as Range

    Set rng = worksheets("NSA").Range("B1:C100")  // update for your Range

    For each cl in rng
        Worksheets("SA").Range(cl.Address) = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(0, 100)
    Next cl
End Sub
```